# Writing Persian in Python with Raspberry Pi3

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can i write farsi in Python environment correctly?
Whenever I want to print a Persian or Arabic word, words are written inappropriately.
In the meantime, I've only got this problem in the raspberry pi 3 and I can literally print Persian words in my pc.

```
 print ('م ا ل س')
```

Comment: پيمان جان علاقمند به همكاري هستي؟ (تهران)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `LANG` in locale to `AR_AA.UTF-8` if you want Default Arabic. Else you can look at the unicode aliases [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.nlsgdrf/support_languages_locales.htm)

Comment: How I can use it?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Do you mean to ask how you can set LANG on your Raspbian or within your python environment?